# A Little Help on my Capstone Project--Converting a Dataset from ASCII into something Python can read

Tags: string, python-3.x, ascii, delimiter, number-formatting

Thanks for reading my post. I am stuck... I am using the National Inpatient Sample (NIS) 2016, which is a data set of seven million hospital records. I need to isolate mothers who gave birth and their newborns, which is 850,00 records.

The data set is in *ASCII* format, which needs to be converted into a format that I can use in Python. From there, I need to use the *ICM-10* codes for all the cases of childbirth, for the mother and her child(ren) to create a new data set that I use for data analytics.

So my steps are..

1--Convert the ASCII into something that Python can use and ensure that the program properly reads the data according to whether is numerical or string. I cannot make this work; can anyone help me with the code?

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from io import StringIO

data=StringIO('C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\NIS_2016\NIS_2016_Core.txt')

np.genfromtxt(data, delimiter=(3,2,2,2,2,11,2,2,3,2,3,2,2,2,3,2,5,

7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,

7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,2,3,

2,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,10,5,

2,2,4,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,

3,3,2,2,10,2,2,4,2))
```

2--Use the ICM-10 codes to create a file that I will work with ...

(I have not yet reached that point yet.)

Many thanks for all your help.

Comment: I don't think this long tuple is your delimiter

Comment: The delimiter is referring to the number of spaces for each column.  The first column has three spaces, the second has two, the third has two and so on...